# Fit text to a div width regardless of text content

Tags: html, css

I have a div, `width:400px;`.

The div contains text, which greets a user, e.g `Hello, John Smith`. I want the text to be dynamically sized to always fit the maximum width of the div, regardless of the text.

So, if the user's name is `Hubert Blaine Wolfeschlegelsteinhausenbergerdorff Sr.`, I want the text to be formatted to not overflow the 400px, with no line break (longer name = smaller text).

I can only find examples of how to do this when the name does not change (just changing the size... is it possible to do it the way I'd like?

Comment: Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container Maybe it helps you out!

Comment: Quintessence of it: https://css-tricks.com/fitting-text-to-a-container/